Subset of a complex manifold whose intersection with every holomorphic curve is analytic
The Osgood's lemma in complex analysis says that if $f \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$  a continuous function such that $f|_{L}$ is holomorphic for every complex line $L \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, then $f$ is holomorphic. I wonder if there is the following geometric analogue of Osgood's lemma:
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $A \subseteq X$ a subset (maybe not too bad, say a submanifold, or maybe it also has some singularities...).

Question. Assume that for every holomorphic curve $C \subset X$ the intersection $A \cap C$ is analytic in $C$ (the latter just means that either $C \subseteq A$ or $A \cap C$ is a discrete set). Is it true that $A$ is
analytic?

One can also ask, is it true that if the intersection of $A \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ with every complex line $L \subset \mathbb{C}^m$ is analytic, then $A$ is analytic. I think this question is stronger, i.e. an affirmative answer to it will also imply a positive answer on the first one by considering a Stein cover and arguing locally.
UPD.: Of course I do not assume the test-curves to be closed, since closed holomorphic curves can simply not exist, as many commentators point out. The question is local, so it can be phrased as follows. Let $U$ be a small neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A \subset U$ a closed subset. Assume that for every holomorphic embedding of a disk $f \colon \Delta \to U$ with $f(0) \in A$ either $f(\Delta) \subseteq A$ or $f(0)$ is an isolated point in $f(\Delta) \cap A$. Is it true that $A$ is analytic?

What exactly do you mean by a holomorphic curve? Do you mean the image of a nonconstant holomorphic map of a Riemann surface? Do you mean a properly embedded complex 1-dimensional submanifold? ...

I guess, an image of a nonconstant map of a Riemann surface. The question is local, so it is enough to check on embedded holomorphic discs.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I will assume that by analytic set you mean complex analytic?  If that is the case, what happens if you take X=\mathbb{C}^2 and A={ (z, \overline{z}) | z\in \mathbb{C} } ? Clearly A is not analytic (it is real analytic - even real algebraic), and since holomorphic curves are also analytic (and therefore also real analytic) their intersection will consist of discrete set of points.

@LukaThaler That does not work, because the complex curve $\left{(z,z)\mid z \in \mathbb{C}\right}$ intersects your $A$ in the real analytic curve $\left{(x,x)\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\right}$.

@ThomasKurbach Indeed, you are totally right! I was to fast with my comment.

I think that the answer is no.
Take a complex torus $X$ without any holomorphic curve. If the result you are asking for were true, it would imply (in the empty sense) that every subset $A \subset X$ is analytic, which is false.
For a counterexample with at least one curve, take $X$ as above, let $X'$ be the blow-up of $X$ at one point, and $E \subset X'$ the exceptional divisor. Then $E$ is the unique complex curve inside $X'$.
Now take any non-analytic subset $A$ of $X'$ such that $A$ is disjoint from $E$ and set $$A' := A \cup E.$$
Thus $E \subset A'$ and your condition is satisfied, but $A'$ is not an analytic subset of $X'$.
Note. The OP edited the question after this answer was posted, changing its meaning.

Of course, I did not assume to test only on the closed curves. The question is local, so you can test on germs of curves (essentially on disks). I added an update to the post.

One can also assume that $X$ is algebraic and ask if it is true that $A \cap C$ is an algebraic subset of $C$ for an algebraic curve $C \subset X$ if and only if $A$ is an algebraic subvariety. But I guess this is a completely different question.

"Of course" in which sense? Osgood's theorem is about lines, so how could one guess that you were talking about germs?  After your update, my answer looks wrong, while it was correct when I wrote it. I think you should have asked another question rather than updating yours after my answer was posted. Anyway, it does not matter...
